# Duplicate / Similar content across many articles

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords, articles

So I am building my website up, so far so good, only 2 categories and about 40 articles. Each category is different and several of the articles in each category are reviews.

My question is this...

I have 500 words of unique content on each review, and then I have around 300+ words of the exact same content across each review (different category different similar content)

The 300 words of similar content is things like..

> Product contains eggs.
>
> product contains milk
>
> product doesn't have support
>
> product company isn't active on social media.
>
> product doesn't have email support.

Things like this, depending on the product and depending on how deep I dive into the reviews they range from 300+ words.

Is it okay to have these reviews with this point back to my category landing page? I mean they're ranking for separate products not the main keyword as my category landing page.
Should I rework my strategy and just take out that similar content?

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be ok. Having similar/duplicate content on pages is common and normal. Especially product pages. As long as it does not make up a significant portion of the content you should be alright.

Of course the question is "how much is too much"? The majority of your content is original (right?) and unique plus the similar/duplicate content isn't keyword stuff but relevant product information. In my estimation this shouldn't be an issue for your site.

Comment: Hey john, thanks for the response my friend.
Yeah, everything is spot on as far as unique content goes besides the same features across several products. I will keep going then, i was just having a moment where i lost a bit of confidence in my technique. My content isn't to game the serps, it is to provide value to my viewers. In a sense i don't need money. Just looking to provide value.

Comment: @user44513 I would add that these more common phrases may seep into your sites keywords as seen in Google Webmasters Tools for what that is worth. It is important to pay attention to this list. It tells Google what your site is about. I had to carefully change some of my repetitive phrases to support the unique keywords found per page. It applied in my case, but may not in yours. Just a friendly note.

Answer (score 0):

The worst that will happen is Google will throw the pages it perceives as duplicates into their omitted index/sandbox (aka they won't really rank). This is **NOT** a case where you will be penalized. Penalties only happen across domains (e.g. if you had duplicate content on two different websites).

I am mostly certain you won't have any real issues. I have worked with large clients who have many franchise location pages, all of which share roughly the same info, save for specifics like address, phone, etc, and they have never been omitted from Google's index.

You're fine.